# simple members inquiry that can be access for members only

Tags: php, sql

I'm creating a membership page 
My login page seems to be okay when entering a account number it display the certain details about the account.
Now I created a two relational tables, I need to add this to the member page? I don't know where to put the code so when I enter the account number and login the details from two relational will automatically display.

Login Code:

```
<p align="center"<h2>Please Sign in to Inquire your Account</h2></p>
<?php
//Start session
session_start();    
//Unset the variables stored in session
unset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);
unset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']);
unset($_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME']);
?>
<form name="loginform" action="login_exec.php" method="post">
<table width="309" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
     <?php
        if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && 
is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
        echo '<ul class="err">';
        foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
            echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
            }
        echo '</ul>';
        unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
        }
    ?>
</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td width="116"><div align="right">Account Number: </div></td>
<td width="177"><input name="Account_Number" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">Password: </div></td>
<td><input name="password" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right"></div></td>
<td><input name="" type="submit" value="Sign in" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

My Members Page Code with one table without the two relational tables:

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');
$id=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member where mem_id='$id'");
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{ 
$fname=$row3['fname'];
$lname=$row3['lname'];
$address=$row3['address'];
$contact=$row3['contact'];
$picture=$row3['picture'];
$gender=$row3['gender']; 
}
?>
</h2>
</span>
<table width="597" border="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="26" colspan="2" class="style11"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="166" rowspan="5" class="style11"><div align="left"><img src="style/LOGO 
GRAY.jpg" alt="no image found"" width="129" height="129" border="1" "<?php echo  
$picture ?>/></div></td>
    <td width="126" valign="top" class="style11"><div align="left">First Name:</div>   
</td>
    <td width="297" valign="top" class="style11"><span class="style16"><?php echo 
$fname ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" class="style11"><div align="left">Last Name:</div></td>
    <td valign="top" class="style11"><span class="style16"><?php echo $lname ?></span> 
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" class="style11"><div align="left">Gender:</div></td>
    <td valign="top" class="style11"><span class="style16"><?php echo $gender ?></span>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" class="style11"><div align="left">Address:</div></td>
    <td valign="top" class="style11"><span class="style16"><?php echo $address ?>  
</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="42" valign="top" class="style11"><div align="left">Contact No.: </div>
</td>
    <td valign="top" class="style11"><span class="style16"><?php echo $contact ?>
</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the code supposedly for the members page with two relational table.
My problem here I don't know how to combine the two.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$memid = 3; // example
$sql = "SELECT member.*, account.* FROM member, account WHERE member.mem_id =  
account.mem_id AND member.mem_id = '".$memid."' ";

mysql_select_db('databaseName');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "Account Number:{$row['Account_Number']}  <br> ".
 "First Name: {$row['fname']} <br> ".
 "Last Name: {$row['lname']} <br> ".
 "Address: {$row['address']} <br> ".
 "Contact: {$row['contact']} <br> ".
 "Share Capital: {$row['Share_Capital']} <br> ".
 "Regular Savings: {$row['Regular_Savings']} <br> ".
 "Power Savings: {$row['Power_Savings']} <br> ".
 "--------------------------------<br>";
 } 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

thanks for helping.

Comment: **Food for thought:** If you ever decide to put in a `header("Location: file.php");` somewhere down the line, you're going to have problems. *"Just saying"*

Comment: By the way, this `<p align="center"<h2>Please Sign in to Inquire your Account</h2></p>` --- missing closing `>` `p` tag ;-)

Comment: I take it that you have `session_start();` inside ALL of your files, right? ;-)

Comment: yes, I have session_start();